# Rust process CSV in parallel

Tags: csv, rust

I am working on a Rust program to read a csv file row wise and perform some operations. My code looks like this. I am using a crate called csv.

```
use csv::ReaderBuilder;
let mut reader = ReaderBuilder::new().from_path("file.csv").unwrap()
```

I am using the records() method to iterate row wise as follows.

```
for result in reader.records() {
        let record = result?;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this iteration by spawning multiple threads since the `records()`
method gives back an iterator?

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/ , which was designed to solve more or less this exact problem

Comment: To be clear, note that the iteration/CSV-parsing itself cannot be parallelized. But `rayon` is indeed a great fit for parallelizing the work you want to do with each record.